# In SQL,How to pick columns which doesnt have 0 value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have pivot query which will result one row of record. I will have to further filter that one row of record. One row of record has hour based columns and so, i have 24 columns for each hour.

How to pick columns which has only values

Lets say we have 5 columns

```
Col1    Col2     Col3  Col4   Col5
100       0            0      20      0
```

Col1, Col4 are eligible.  I need total these two columns.

```
Col1  Col4      Total
100    20          120



create table #t
(
Col0 int,
Col1 int,
Col2 int,
Col3 int,
Col4 int,
Col5 int,
Col6 int,
Col7 int,
Col8 int,
Col9 int,
Col10 int,
Col11 int

)



insert into #t values
(0,100,0,0,0,0,20,10,0,0,0,0)

select * from #t
-- Expected Result

select Col1, Col6, Col7 from #t
```

Comment: Please post the query and try explaining again.

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need a WHERE condition in the unpivoted query that filters out NULL values, but we'll need to see your query before we can give you a more specific answer.

Comment: you should be posting the query as well so we can help

Comment: @MichaelWayne, I am really sorry.. I have included sample query..

Comment: Your table will have only one row? What if it has multiple rows? how the out put will look like if there are multiple rows with different columns having zero in them? Can you provide the use case details what you want to achieve?

Comment: It will have only one row. Because this is  the output of my Pivot query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that using a static pivot table, dynamic perhaps. It is not known when a pivot table is defined if all the values are null or not and by the time the data is piped in it is too late. You can either create a reporting project that supports omitting empty column groups or look for a more dynamic query alternative.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by create a reporting project that supports omitting empty columns ?

Comment: For example, in SSRS, your problem would be solved by creating a column group on your id field and placing a filter on the column group for SUM()<>0. However, this does not answer your question, just another option. You would have to generate dynamic sql to do this in SSMS.

Comment: So basically at this moment, we cant do nothing. We cant filter the columns which has values and no values ..

Comment: @goofyui - Not without using dynamic sql to create your pivot.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to hear the Dynamic SQL. I did some search online ,able to find some materials.